# Help with mixing text and Image ind a listView

Tags: android, image, listview, android-listview, android-imageview

My application is fetching data from a Xml file on a webpage. That date is placed in a listView. In the XML file there is a link to a image for every item. I need some help figuring out the easiest way to get that image from the xml file into the listView together with the text.

In my code right now i have just placed a static image in the android:src ="" in the layout file.

Screenshot:

[image]

xmlfile:

http://roskilde-festival.dk/typo3conf/ext/tcpageheaderobjects/xml/bandobjects_251_uk.xml

MainClass:

```
package com.bandreminder;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class bandR extends ListActivity {

    private ConnectivityManager connMgr;

    private android.net.NetworkInfo network_info;
    private boolean blnNetworkAccess=false;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);



        connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        network_info = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if(network_info != null && network_info.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            blnNetworkAccess = true;
        }

       if(blnNetworkAccess) {


        fetchData();

        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(bandR.this, "No Internet connection, please enable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        if(network_info != null && network_info.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            Log.w("resume", ""+network_info);
        }

        else {
            Toast.makeText(bandR.this, "No Internet connection, please enable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        blnNetworkAccess = false;
        Log.w("onPause", "test");
    }


    private void fetchData() {



        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        Integer numResults;
        String xml = XmlHandler.getXML();

        Document doc = XmlHandler.XMLfromString(xml);

        numResults = XmlHandler.numResults(doc);


         if((numResults <= 0)){
            Toast.makeText(bandR.this, "No Bands found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
            finish();
         }

        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {                           
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    

            Element e = (Element)nodes.item(i);
            map.put("artistName", "Artist Name: "+ XmlHandler.getValue(e, "artistName"));
            map.put("country", "Country: " + XmlHandler.getValue(e, "country"));

            map.put("scene", "Scene: " + XmlHandler.getValue(e, "scene"));
            map.put("tidspunkt", "Tidspunkt: " + XmlHandler.getValue(e, "tidspunkt"));


            mylist.add(map);            
        }       


         ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.main, 
                         new String[] { "artistName", "country", "scene","tidspunkt" }, 
                         new int[] { R.id.item_artistname, R.id.item_country,R.id.scene ,R.id.tidspunkt});

         setListAdapter(adapter);




         final ListView lv = getListView();
         lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true); 
         lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                   
                Toast.makeText(bandR.this, "artistName '" + o.get("artistName") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

            }
        });
    }



}
```

XMLHandler Class:

```
package com.bandreminder;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import android.util.Log;


public class XmlHandler{

    public static boolean connected;

public boolean getConnected(){

        return connected;

    }

    public final static Document XMLfromString(String xml){

        Document doc = null;

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is); 


        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            System.out.println("XML parse error: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            System.out.println("Wrong XML file structure: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("I/O exeption: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;

    }

    /** Returns element value
      * @param elem element (it is XML tag)
      * @return Element value otherwise empty String
      */
     public final static String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
         Node kid = null;
         if( elem != null){
             if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
                 for( kid = elem.getFirstChild(); kid != null; kid = kid.getNextSibling() ){
                     if( kid.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                         return kid.getNodeValue();
                     }
                 }
             }
             else

                 return  elem.getNodeValue();
         }
         return "";
     }

     public static String getXML(){
        ;
            String line = null;
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                // Send data
                URL url = new URL("http://roskilde-festival.dk/typo3conf/ext/tcpageheaderobjects/xml/bandobjects_251_uk.xml");
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                // Get the response
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                while((line = rd.readLine()) != null){
                    result.append(line);
                }
                //Close
                rd.close();
            } catch (Exception e){
                connected = false;

            }

            return result.toString();
    }

    public static int numResults(Document doc){     
        Node results = doc.getDocumentElement();

        int res = -1;



        try{

            res += results.getChildNodes().getLength();




        }catch(Exception e ){

            Log.w("Exception numresults", ""+e.getMessage());
            res = -1;
        }
        Log.w("numres", ""+String.valueOf(res));
        return res-1;
    }

    public static String getValue(Element item, String str) {       
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);
        Log.w("element", ""+n.item(0).getTextContent());

        //return XmlHandler.getElementValue(n.item(0));
        return n.item(0).getTextContent();
    }



}
```

Layout:

listplaceholder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">    

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="No data"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="7dp"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    >
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/item_artistname"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:textSize="15dp" />
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/item_country"
    android:layout_below="@id/item_artistname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:textSize="13dp" />
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/scene"
    android:layout_below="@id/item_country"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:textSize="13dp" />
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/tidspunkt"
    android:layout_below="@id/scene"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:textSize="13dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"

    android:layout_below="@id/item_artistname"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/abe"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have image urls in xml file. Extract the urls like you do with other values.
You must to implement your own adapter which will load images and bind them to image view in rows.

There is answer for loading images:
[Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)